# Как преобразовать ComboBox.SelectedItem при изменении ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть ComboBox

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```

При изменении ItemsSource я могу получить ошибку в SelectedItem. Тк в новом наборе выбранного значения не будет. Мне надо, что бы при изменении источника данных в ComboBox выбирался всегда первый элемент или только в том случае, если такой элемент будет недоступен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите у комбобокса `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`, возможно подойдёт для ваших целей.

Comment: Да, это в общем то, что нужно. Хотя если мне потребовалось бы несколько независимых комбобоксов с единым источником, то уже не подошло бы это.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Не представляю как это могло бы помочь. Значение ComboBox у меня привязано к свойству ViewModel.

Comment: Ну так на то и расчёт. А что по вашему изменилось и почему это не может помочь? (Помимо того, что не помог копипаст). Кстати, код ViewModel'a был бы тоже кстати

Comment: К слову сказать, в XAML коде важен порядок указания аттрибутов, так что ещё одним возможным решением может быть замена местами, так как считается правильным сначала указать SelectedItem, а потом уже ItemsSource.

Comment: А смысл. Потом то Источник может поменяться

Comment: У вас ViewModel что-ли может поменяться? Опишите подробнее что у вас в программе происходит.

Comment: Источник данных ComboBox привязан к ListBox, это видно из примера. Пользователь может щелкать на листбоксе, что будет менять источник данных у комбобокса. Значение комбобокса привязано к свойству ViewModel